# Oracle SQL query to remove whitespace before comma

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, oracle11g

I have a comma separated string like

`This,is ,a,beautiful  ,summer day`

Can you please help me remove the WHITESPACE before "comma", without removing the space between two words?

Tried below query:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('This,is ,a,beautiful  ,summer day'  , '[[:space:]]', null ) regexp
  FROM dual;
```

but it's removing the space between summer day.

Output:

`This,is,a,beautiful,summerday`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace multiple spaces using:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(
         'This,is ,a,beautiful  ,summer day'  ,
         '[[:space:]]+,',
         ','
       ) regexp
FROM   dual;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | REGEXP                         |
> | :----------------------------- |
> | This,is,a,beautiful,summer day |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7e042a59dabc0bb93e5ef6065f1ab519)*

Answer (score 1):

As you said - replace it:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'This,is ,a,beautiful ,raining day' from dual)
  3           --This,is,a,beautiful,summerday
  4  select replace(col, ' ,', ',') result                 --> this
  5  from test;     

RESULT
-------------------------------
This,is,a,beautiful,raining day

SQL>
```